# How to change the color of multiple objects with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change the color of multiple objects (footer, divs, text) background and text color, with one button. I tried using button javascript, but I don't want name multiple objects button in order to change their color.
Thanks

Comment: Hello. What have you tried to do for this? Show your code pls.

Comment: By using a class selector?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
First create a button HTML whit the id "btnChangeColor"

```
<button id="btnChangeColor" class="btn btn-primary">Change Color</button>
```

With JavaScript add the listener and with the DOM get all elements to change.

```
const btnChangeColor =    document.querySelector('#btnChangeColor');
const footer =            document.querySelector('footer');
const divs =              document.querySelectorAll('div');

btnChangeColor.addEventListener('click', () => {
    footer.classList.add('custom-theme');
    divs.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.add('custom-theme');
    });
});
```

You can custom the class CSS (custom-theme) with the values with you prefer

```
.custom-theme {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```