# How to change the color of multiple objects with one button? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change the color of multiple objects (footer, divs, text) background and text color, with one button. I tried using button javascript, but I don't want name multiple objects button in order to change their color.

```
<button id="primary">CLICK</button>

let btnPrimary = document.querySelector('#primary');

btnPrimary.addEventListener('click', ()=> btnPrimary.style.backgroundColor='#337ab7')
```

Comment: Please show an html example. You have to target those elements somehow either by looking at their parent or by className etc but we have no idea what they look like. See [mcve]. Also please take the time to read [ask]

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question. You already asked this same question [How to change the color of multiple objects with one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603996/how-to-change-the-color-of-multiple-objects-with-one-button) just a few minutes before this one. If you have anything to add you can use the [edit] link to update your question.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is to toggle a class on `body`

```
.a {
  background: green;
}

.b {
  background: pink;
}

.c {
  background: yellow;
}
body.alt .a {
  background: blue;
}

body.alt .b {
  background: blue;
}

body.alt .c {
  background: blue;
}
```

Then all you need to do is create a function to toggle "alt"

```
function (e) {
  document.body.classList.toggle("alt");
}();
```